# Keep getting 'Undefined index' while index is there, Works perfectly in online editor but not in project?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuex

Iam creating a dashboard with php, laravel and Vue (&vuex). Another user of Stackoverflow has helped me tremendously and came up with the following code to extract the values that i want (only the 'Result' & 'result') from the dataset that i get back from the laravel API.
His code seems to work perfect in every online PHP editor. But as soon as i want to try to use it in my project i get an ERROR back that says "Undefined index: result". What causes this and how would i be able to solve this?

I cant seem to get my head around the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**The code:**

```
$data = Log::all('RESPONSE');
$results_decoded = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($results_decoded as $inner_val){
            if (isset($inner_val["Result"][0]["ERRORS"])) $result_array[] = $inner_val["Result"][0]["ERRORS"];
            else $result_array[] = $inner_val['result'];

        }

        return json_encode($result_array);
```

**var_export() - The dataset:**

```
$results_decoded = array ( 
0 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049', ), ), ),
1 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211048', ), ), ), 
2 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211050', ), ), ), 
3 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211050', ), ), ), 
4 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049', ), ), ), 
5 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211046', ), ), ), 
6 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211045', ), ), ), 
7 => array ( 'result' => '2007: New Web Order created successfully', ), 
8 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211046', ), ), ));
```

**The perfecty working example in a online PHP editor:**
live demo: https://3v4l.org/TEPab

**The Desired array of result:**

```
["99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211048",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211050",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211050",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211046",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211045",
"2007: New Web Order created successfully",
"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211046"]
```

**My code (using in project):**

```
        $data = Log::all('RESPONSE');
        $results_decoded = json_decode($data, true);

        $result_array = [];
        foreach ($results_decoded as $inner_val){
            if (isset($inner_val["Result"][0]["ERRORS"])) $result_array[] = $inner_val["Result"][0]["ERRORS"];
            else $result_array[] = $inner_val['result'];

        }
```

Comment: Debug... you _think_ your array contains something which is not true.. look into the *real* values instead of assuming things

Comment: But why does it work in the online editor? its the exact same dataset. @LarsStegelitz

Comment: I've been working on this for numerous days hehe...

Comment: The 7th element has the key 'result' and no array, what index is it that fails?

Comment: Apparently its not.. there must be some difference, either in the code, the data or both. I know, it's not a satisfying answer, but PHP does not lie to you, for sure

Comment: there must be a problem with other parts of your code, maybe you have another `$results_decoded` array or refill it somewhere else. or anything else, but for sure there is no problem with Laravel or PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Explanation:***

If I am getting right, and array keys are `Result` and `result` in your described array, then this code would be right.

```
$results_decoded = array ( 
0 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049', ), ), ),
1 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211048', ), ), ), 
2 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211050', ), ), ), 
3 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211050', ), ), ), 
4 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049', ), ), ), 
5 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211046', ), ), ), 
6 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211045', ), ), ), 
7 => array ( 'result' => '2007: New Web Order created successfully', ), 
8 => array ( 'Result' => array ( 0 => array ( 'ERRORS' => '99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211046', ), ), ));

foreach ($results_decoded as $inner_val){
    $result_array[] = $inner_val["Result"][0]["ERRORS"] ?? $inner_val['result'] ?? '';    
}

$result_array = array_values($result_array);

echo json_encode($result_array);
```

Demo Link: https://3v4l.org/nRCQS

Comment: Hi @Hitesh thank you for your quickresponse. I seem to get an array back of strings back containing nothing. ```["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]``` Does this have something to do with laravel? Because your code seems to work perfectly aswell in the online editor :)

Comment: As I have told you if your array is like this as I have shown in the fiddle it should work. @DeckChain

Comment: based on your comment to this answer, you are iterating over something that has 31 elements!  the array in your question has 9 elements. look for your problem in your code.

Comment: I took a snapshot of the response, it was too long to post in the comment ;) it is iterating over the full dataset. But returns empty strings. Would that mean there is no ```$inner_value['result'] ```?

Comment: I have to show the data. which you are getting, just take a screenshot of some data and attach it to your question. so, we can see it there.@DeckChain